# Should I embed interface from standard library or write my own?

Tags: go, interface

There are some common interfaces in Go's standard library, e.g, the [io.Closer](https://pkg.go.dev/io#Closer):

```golang
type Closer interface {
    Close() error
}
```

If I would want to define an interface in my code that has a `Close` method, would I embed `io.Closer` like this:

```golang
type example interface {
    io.Closer

    // ... some other functions or embedded types
}
```

or would I just define the function itself like:

```golang
type example interface {
    Close() error

    // ... some other functions or embedded types
}
```

Is there any best practice for this?

Comment: Most of stdlib packages use `io.Closer`. Example: https://pkg.go.dev/mime/multipart#File
. Old code defines `Close()` directly: https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/cmd/pack/pack.go#L230

Comment: It is common to use `io.Closer` when the `Close` means "end input/output and release resources used by this thing".    If the `Close` method has some other meaning, then it's probably best to declare and document the method in your interface declaration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For such common and simple interfaces I would definately embed the one from the standard lib (such as [`io.Closer`](https://pkg.go.dev/io#Closer), [`io.Reader`](https://pkg.go.dev/io#Reader) and [`io.ByteReader`](https://pkg.go.dev/io#ByteReader)).

But not any interface type. In general interfaces should be defined where they are needed. Embedding any interface defined in other packages (including the standard library) has the danger of failing to implicitly implement them if they are changed or extended.

The "owner" (definer) of the package may change it (e.g. extend it with a new method) and properly update all its types implementing it, so the package can continue to work from the outside, but obviously the package owner will not update your implementations.

For example the `reflect.Type` interface type had no `Type.ConvertibleTo()` method back in [Go 1.0](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect@go1#Type), it was added in [Go 1.1](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect@go1.1#Type). The same thing may happen: interfaces in the standard lib may get altered or extended in future Go versions, resulting in your existing code failing to implement them.

What's the difference between small, common interfaces and the "rest"? *The bigger the interface, the weaker the abstraction* – so goes the Go proverb. Small interfaces like `io.Closer` and `io.Reader` capture a tiny yet important functionality. They are so common, "every" library tries to implement them, every utility functions build upon them. I don't ever expect them to change. If there will be a reason to change / extend them, they will be rather added as new interfaces. Not like bigger interfaces where abstraction is harder to capture accurately. They have a better chance to change / evolve over time.

Comment: The first paragraph of your of your answer somewhat contradicts your following explanation. Why should `io.Closer` be an exception of the general rule? What are the benefits of using `io.Closer` over `Close() error`?